# What is the best head set for a metal fork on a carbon frame?

Tags: fork, carbon, headset

I want to put a Chris King or cane Creek headset on a 29 inch carbon fiber frame using a rock shox SID fork.   What is the  best headset for this?

Comment: Aside from someone making a table of requirements of headset vs frame vs fork compatibility, theres not an objective way to answer this. Talk to your bike shop -- chances are they'll be involved in the installation anyway and picking your parts.